# SQL Server - sensitive data in backup after truncate table

Tags: sql-server

I have a Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 database with about 50GB of customer data and about 500MB of non-customer-specific data like inventory, parts, terminology, etc.  I generate a clean copy of the database with no customer data for testing using the following rough procedure (it's fully scripted):

1. Backup production database to file
2. Restore file to test database (SIMPLE recovery mode at this point)
3. Meticulously curated TRUNCATE TABLE/DELETE statements to remove all customer data from database
4. INSERT a few test customers back in so it is minimally usable
5. Shrink database+shrink log on test database
6. Backup test database to "clean" backup file

Now, we are going to allow outside developers to get a copy of the clean backup file produced in the last step instead of just SQL server (query) access to the test database.

My Question: Can I be sure that all pages/extents with customer sensitive database been zeroed/removed as of step 6 (if the backup file itself were opened with a hex editor)?  What about covering indexes, will there still be possibly 'dirty' pages?  I'm sure there is chapter-and-verse answer for this but I can't seem to find it online.

Follow-on question: I'm backing up and restoring 50+GB to end up with a 500MB database.  500MB is still more than I would want to replay back via INSERT statements into an empty database.  Is there a better way to clone the structure of 300 tables and also structure+data on 50 tables?  We make at least 2 significant schema changes per month (new tables, new columns, remove columns, etc).  The current script takes perhaps 10 minutes to run so I am fine as is, but would like to improve if possible.

Comment: Is the non-customer-specific data in separate tables, or intermingled with the client data?

Comment: I'm wondering if it'd be more efficient to script out all the DB table create states and IF EXIST DROP and then use SELECT TOP 0 to insert only the schema. While this may take longer to get setup initially, you may find it a lot more efficient than copying 50 GB and doing all the other operations, etc. Just drop all the tables and objects you script over with SELECT TOP 0 records since it's just copying the column definitions. Just a quick idea from a process I recall helping maintain and make more resilient (I didn't write the procedure tho) for schema changes, etc. for a DB refresh

Comment: And it was a DB refresh from a main DB with multi customer data that we only got the one customer data from to put into their own DB that refreshed nightly. We also used VIEWs with filtered logic on the main DBs in some instances and only allowed the accounts to have access to those views with explicit permissions setup accordingly via AD. The VIEWs would use WHERE clauses, etc. to ensure on that customers data was able to be viewed.... Just some quick ideas off the top of my head without look at a server or any old scripts, etc. which I have slews of by the way.